# Problem with multiple ListBox binding same SelectedItem property

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a screen in WPF that needs to list data from same database table, but separately by status. In the print each column is a different status and each is a ListBox, the SelectedItem binding for all ListBox is the same property in ViewModel. The problem is when an item is selected in some ListBox it still selected even after I select an item from other ListBox and when the focus return to the first ListBox (with Tab key for example) the item gets the selected style. Any idea how to resolve this? I can change the ListBoxes for other solution too, at this moment i can't see other solution.
Sorry for my bad English, and I don't know if the explanation is much clear this feature is a bit complicated to explain, but any doubts I'll provide the answers.

Thanks for all.

[image: print of my Screen]

Comment: Show your XAML and your view model code in order to get help. Do you invoke the PropertyChanged event?

Comment: I added the PropertyChanged and seems works. If I found other error I post again here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

do you want to have the same item selected in each listbox? Try adding `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="true"` to every listbox in xaml:

```
<StackPanel>
    <!--both comboboxes are synchronized with each other-->
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: I had forgotten the PropertyChanged on the SelectedItem property in my ViewModel. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @AlexandreHeinen this one works without propertychanged if you want to achieve a synchronisation between SelectedItems in listBoxes which have the same ItemSource bound.